# Is it mandatory to catch up a git feature branch?

Tags: git

I've arrived in this team and when we are about to merge (after providing a feature build which was tested), the team process asks to catch up the commits from the main branch via a merge `master` into `myfeaturebranch` before doing the "official" merge into `master`.

(rebase is out of topic here, it's problematic since we use AzureDevops and rebase changes commit SHAs and therefore commit links in tickets)

I'd like to know if catching up is mandatory? Is the standard merge enough knowing nobody worked before or there is no impact? Is it overkill?

EDIT, some clarifications after the answer and comments : we don't use PRs (someone just makes a local merge to check the differences). Fast-forward merges are in discussion but not used at the moment (I consider a merge commit shows better "I've finished my feature and here it is" instead of multiple commits next to each other on the main branche - I know squash but it's not used again because of AzureDevops links)

Thanks!

Comment: Side Note, I use AzDO also, and we decided that even though (as you mentioned) some work items may get duplicate commit links due to rebasing, that's still better than all the extra back-merges in the permanent history. One way to prevent the dups is to link work items to the PR instead of the individual commits. This way devs can rebase onto `main` all day long. (We also use Semi-Linear merge when completing the PR.) There are some devs though that always link commits despite this advice...you can remove the links manually in the work item if you care; we usually just ignore them.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, requiring people to either rebase or merge to update their branch before completing a PR, IMHO is probably overkill *most of the time*. But unless you can somehow know when it's truly needed, having it as a required standard may be a decent idea.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no, it's not required *by Git* in any *technical* sense.  It may of course be "required" in the sense that this is your company's or team's work-flow and people will be upset if you don't follow it.  It may also be required, not because of Git, but because of the use of low-capability tooling.  To see what is going on, it's important to understand how `git merge` works.

To understand how `git merge` works, start with understanding commits:

- Each commit is uniquely numbered (with a big ugly random-looking hash ID, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)).  Every Git repository everywhere uses the *same* hash ID for that exact commit, even if that Git repository does not have that commit yet.  So if two different repositories have the same number, they hold the same commit.  If only one has the number, that one repository has the commit; the other repository can get that commit from the one that has it.

  (This is how `git fetch` and `git push` work: they just exchange the IDs to figure out what needs synchronization.)

  To make that work, all parts of every commit are frozen for all time: nothing in any commit can ever be changed.
- Each commit contains two sub-parts: it has a *full snapshot of every file*, and it has some *metadata*.  (The snapshot is stored in a special Git-only format with the files compressed and their data de-duplicated, so that the repository doesn't bloat up even though most commits mostly re-use most of the files.)
- The metadata *in* each snapshot include things like author and date-and-time, but also include—for Git's own use and built by Git at commit time—a list of raw hash IDs of *earlier* (or *parent* ) commits.  This list usually has just one entry, but it's a list so that it can have none, or two+ entries, even though that's rare.

The stored parent hash ID(s) link later commits *backwards* to earlier commits.  This *is* the history in the repository: the commits are the history, and history is merely the set of commits.  Each commit has a full set of every file.  There is no *file* history, there are just *commits*.  To see if some file changed between commits `C` (`C` standing in for some `C`ommit hash ID) and subsequent commit `D`, we have Git extract *both* commits' files and compare them.  The de-duplication makes this comparison trivial for duplicated files (no actual extraction is required) so only *different* files need extracting, after which Git runs a differential analysis engine over them to see what changed, like playing a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference).

A *branch name* in Git simply holds one commit hash ID.  By definition, whatever hash ID is *in* some branch name *is* the *latest* commit for that branch: Git calls this the *tip* commit.  But two or more names can select the *same* commit, so if we have a chain of commits that ends at some hash that we'll call `H`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

and we have two names `br1` and `br2` that *both* contain hash ID `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1, br2
```

then *both branches contain all the same commits* and both end at commit `H`.  It won't matter which branch name we pick: `git switch br1` or `git switch br2` will have Git extract, into our working area, all the files from commit `H`.  Let's say we do that with `br1`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2
```

But now we make a *new commit* (with whatever new snapshot).  Git will write out this new commit such that it gets a new, unique hash ID, and points backwards to `H` as its parent.  Git will then store the new hash ID, which we'll call `I`, in the *name* `br1`, resulting in:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2
```

The two branch names now select *different* commits so now it *does* matter which name we use.  We make a second new commit on `br1`, for no obvious reason, and get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2
```

Then we `git switch br2`.  Git removes, from the work area, the files that go with commit `J`, and installs instead the files that go with commit `H`, and we now have:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

Note how the special name `HEAD`, written in all capitals, is *attached to* one *branch name*.  That's the *branch name* we're using, and that branch name points to one commit—the *tip* commit for that branch—and that's the *commit* that we are using.

If we now make two new commits here, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We are now set up to do a `git merge`.

#### Merge is about combining work

The point of a `git merge` operation is to *combine work done*.  But what exactly is "work done"?  There are a lot of ways one *could* define this, but what Git does is use the same spot-the-difference code.  We pick some common starting commit—some point where our two branches<sup>1</sup> diverge—and use the snapshot that's in *that* commit as the common starting point.  Here, that point is obvious: it's commit `H`.  Commit `G` or earlier would work too, but `H` is the *last* one that works, so it's the *best*.  If we went back any further we'd see changes made from `G` to `H` in our comparison output, which we don't need.  If we didn't go this far back, we would be at commit `I` or `J` or `K` or `L` and none of those *work*.

So, Git now runs *two* `git diff` operations:

- One diff compares all the files in snapshot `H` to all the files in snapshot `J`.  Note how Git skips right over snapshot `I`: it doesn't *need* it, because every commit is complete unto itself.
- The second diff compares all the files in snapshot `H` to all the files in snapshot `L`.

The first diff shows the work done in branch `br1`.  The second diff shows the work done in branch `br2`.<sup>2</sup>  Git calls commit `H` the *merge base*, and of course `J` and `L` are the *tip commits* of our two branch names.  So diffing the base against the two tip commits finds the work that was done.

Because this work starts from *one common starting point*—the snapshot in commit `H`—it's now a trivial (?) matter of *combining the diffs*.  That's basically what `git merge` does here: if we changed line 3 of `README.txt`, and they changed line 17, Git just takes both changes.  If we changed some file and they didn't, Git takes our changes.  If they changed some file and we didn't, Git takes their changes.  Where we both changed some file, Git takes *both* changes.

There's one [fly in this ointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_in_the_ointment) though: what if we changed line 3 of `README.txt`, and they also changed line 3, and we both made *different changes?*  Git's answer to this is to declare a *merge conflict*.  If we and they make the *exact same* changes to the same lines, that's OK: Git takes one copy of those changes.  Otherwise—if we touched the same lines but in different ways—Git declares a merge conflict.  Git also declares a merge conflict even if our changes merely "touch at the edges": there must be least one unchanged line *between* our changes and their changes for Git to decide that these are independent changes.<sup>3</sup>

In any case, *if* Git decides that it can completely merge the two sets of changes, Git will do that on its own.  These merged changes are then applied to the snapshot from commit `H`.  That keeps our work on `br1` while adding the work from `br2`, or keeps our work from `br2` while adding the work from `br1`.  Then Git makes a new *merge commit*, which we can draw like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

Note that I've taken the *branch names* away from this diagram, and that's relevant to your original question.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you pay attention here, you'll note that the word *branch* sometimes means *branch name*, but sometimes means *a series of commits starting at some point and ending at some other point*.  The word *branch* may also mean yet other things.  Humans (and Git) abuse this word, torturing it to the point where it almost stops meaning anything at all.  You often have to guess what someone meant when they said "branch".

<sup>2</sup>Note that except for needing to find the right *commits* and then the commit *relationships*, which are what form the "branch-ness" of the *commit graph*, Git doesn't actually need or use "branches" at all here.  Everything is all about *commits*.  That is, Git used the name `br1` to find commit `J`, and the name `br2` to find commit `L`.  From then on, Git just used the commits.  It's the commits that lead backwards to the earlier commits, and once the two lines of commits meet up, that's the common starting point commit.

<sup>3</sup>Exercise: is this always correct?  What if we and they both changed a column of numbers to be summed, and we both added `5`, but the correct result is to add 5 *twice?*  When are Git's conflict resolution rules right and when are they wrong?  Is demanding that changes don't abut actually required?

(There's no one answer to these questions that is *always* correct.  The goal of this exercise is to get you to think about what Git is doing here, so that you can tell if it's right *for you*.)

---

#### What happens to the branch names

Let's put the branch names back in, and show which branch we're "on"—as in `git status` says `on branch br1` or `on branch br2`—when we start:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Here, we're "on" `br1` when we start.  In this case the merge result looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

As always, whenever Git makes a *new commit* like `M`, Git writes the new commit's hash ID, whatever it turns out to be, into the *current branch name*.  Since we were on `br1` before, we're still on `br1` now.

**If we run the `git merge` while "on" `br2`, the result looks the same, except now it's `br2`, not `br1`, that points to `M`**, and `br1` still points to `J`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br2 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

The *snapshot* in commit `M` is the same either way, because of Git's rules about combining changes.

There is another difference, though, in these two.  Whenever Git makes a new *merge commit*, the merge commit has *two* parents instead of the usual single parent.  New merge commit `M` points back to both `I` *and* `L`.  But the list of parents, in a merge commit, is an *ordered* list.  One of the parents is specifically the *first* parent.

Git arranges for that first parent to be the commit that the updated branch name pointed to, before the update.  That is, if we have `br1` pointing to `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \₁
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /²
          K--L   <-- br2
```

then the *first* parent of `M` is `J`, because `br1` used to point to `J`.  Using `git log --first-parent`, we'll view the *commit history* as commit `M`, then commit `J`, then commit `I`, then commit `H`: commits `L` and `K` will *never show up*.

If we run the merge with `br2` as our current branch name, though, the *first* parent will be `L`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \₂
...--G--H      M   <-- br2 (HEAD)
         \    /¹
          K--L
```

Following only the first parent link backwards from `M` produces `M`, then `L`, then `K`, then `H`, then `G` and so on, as if commits `I-J` never existed.

**If you ever plan to use the `--first-parent` option of `git log`** you will want to carefully control *which branch you're on* when you run `git merge`.  You will merge *from* a feature, *into* the main line.  That way `git log --first-parent` will follow only the main line, not the feature branch.  That is, by merging the features into the main line, we get a picture that looks like this:

```
          S----S----S   <-- feature S
         /           \
...--o--o--o--o--TM--SM--o--...   <-- mainline
            \    /
             T--T   <-- feature T
```

but running `git log --first-parent` while on `mainline` never shows the feature branches, only the marked `T` and `S` merge commits `TM` and `SM`.

If you will never use `--first-parent`, this won't really matter.

#### Handling merge conflicts

Sometimes, `git merge` can't do the job on its own.  Worse, sometimes `git merge` *thinks* it can do the job on its own, but does it wrong; see the exercise in footnote 3.

When Git *does* get a merge wrong, what happens?  Well, if Git *knows* it can't merge—if it stops in the *middle of the merge* with a merge conflict—then you, the programmer, get to clean up the mess.  **In general, the fix-conflict situation requires command line Git or something equally powerful.**  Most on-line hosting systems (GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, and so on) cannot handle the general case.  A few of them have some specific cases they can deal with, but if your hosting system doesn't, you have to do this merge locally, with real Git software (and/or perhaps with some merge tool assistance).

Git literally just stops in the middle of the merge.  Git writes, to your working tree, its best effort at merging the conflicted file(s), along with conflict markers to show you where Git was unable to combine work.  Git also leaves, in Git's *index* (which we haven't discussed at all here), *all three input files:* the version from the merge base commit and the two branch-tip versions.  A merge tool can invoke Git to gain access to all three of these inputs to help you do the merge manually, or you can use `git mergetool` to invert the order of these operations: `git mergetool` will, for each conflicted file, extract the three inputs and run some command *on* those files.

No matter what you do here, your job is to produce the *correct merged result* and tell Git to put that result back into Git's index (from which Git actually makes each new commit snapshot).  You might do this by editing the file with the conflict markers, fixing it up, writing that out, and running `git add` on the resulting file.  **Whatever you tell Git the conflict resolution is, Git believes you.**  Git doesn't check whether you used all the inputs: it just believes that you, the programmer, provided the *correct merged result file*.  Git will put that file into the merge snapshot.  **By definition, whatever is in the merge snapshot is the correct merge result.**

#### Future merges use the merged snapshot

Let's take a look at what *repeated* merging looks like.  We start out with a main line and a feature branch:

```
...--o--*--G--H   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

Here `C` is the latest feature-branch commit.  Meanwhile the "main line" branch has had a few new commits added as well (I called them `G-H` here).  Commit `*` will be the merge base if and when we merge.  If we switch *to* the main line and merge, we get:

```
...--o--*--G--H---M   <-- mainline (HEAD)
         \       /
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

We can now *switch back to the feature branch* and continue working, resulting in, say:

```
...--o--*--G--H---M--I   <-- mainline
         \       /
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- feature
```

A *future* merge has to find the merge base between `mainline` and `feature`.  That's the latest commit that's on *both branches*.  But note that commit `M`, on `mainline`, links back to `C`.  So if we start at `I` at the right edge of `mainline` and work backwards, we hit `M`, then we hit another commit `H` on the top *and* commit `C` on the bottom.  Meanwhile, if we start at `E` and work backwards, we hit commit `D` and then `C`.  **This means commit `C` is the merge base for the next merge.**

What this really means is that Git doesn't have to look at what changed in `A` and `B`, as those are included in `M` anyway.  We are therefore much less likely to have any merge conflicts: they can only come from the last commit `I` on `mainline` itself.

We *could* merge the other way:

```
...--o--*--G-----H   <-- mainline
         \        \
          A--B--C--M   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

If we then continue working on `feature` and add `D` and `E`, while we get some commit `I` on `mainline` as before, we have this:

```
...--o--*--G-----H--I   <-- mainline
         \        \
          A--B--C--M--D--E   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The merge base of `I` and `E` is now commit `H`, because commit `M` leads back to *both* `H` *and* `C`.  Once again, merging doesn't have to look at a bunch of earlier commits; only commits `E` and `I` matter, and the only source of conflicts for our feature branch, if we are to finally merge it into `mainline` for real now, is commit `I`:

```
...--o--*--G-----H--I------N   <-- mainline (HEAD)
         \        \       /
          A--B--C--M--D--E   [was `feature`, now has no name]
```

#### This finally gets us back to your original question

> ... the team process asks to catch up the commits from the main branch via a merge `master` into `myfeaturebranch` before doing the "official" merge into `master`.

This looks like the last graph above.  We have the feature branch, but it ends at a merge commit `M` that links back to `master`:

```
...--*--G--H--I--J   <-- master
      \           \
       A--B--C--D--M   <-- feature
```

If we switch to branch `master` and run `git merge feature`, something odd happens.  We can *prevent* the odd thing from happening by supplying the `--no-ff` option to `git merge`.  If we do that, Git will find the *merge base* for commits `J` and `M` in the usual way:

```
...--*--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
      \           \
       A--B--C--D--M   <-- feature
```

We start at `M` and work backwards as needed, and start at `J` and work backwards as needed.  By not moving from `J` at all, while moving from `M` to `J`, we arrive at a commit that is on *both branches*, namely commit `J`.  So that's our merge base.

According to the rules for `git merge`, we must now run two diff commands.  One will compare the merge base—commit `J`—against the current branch's tip commit `J`.  Obviously every file in `J` is exactly the same as every file in `J`, so this diff is *completely empty*.

The other diff will compare every file in `J` to every file in the snapshot in commit `M`.  These are all the changes in the feature branch, already merged.  Note that if the feature branch commit `D` was tested and passed *and* commit `M` was *also* tested and passed the tests, the files in commit `M` all pass the tests.

According to the next step of the merge rules, we're supposed to add all the changes found by going from `J` to `J`–i.e., no changes at all—to all the changes found by going from `J` to `M`.  Those are all the changes in `M` that exist because of the feature branch.

The result of adding all those changes, then applying those changes to the files from `J`, are *exactly the files from commit `M`*.  That's just your basic algebra: adding nothing to something produces the original something.  So we get our new merge commit `N`, which goes into the system like this:

```
...--*--G--H--I--J---N   <-- master (HEAD)
      \           \ /
       A--B--C--D--M   <-- feature
```

In commit `N`, *all the files match all the files in the snapshot for commit `M`*.  This is *guaranteed* by the rules of merging!

Because it's guaranteed—and because it's silly to bother diffing `J` against `J` in the first place—`git merge` will, **if it is allowed to do this**, not bother merging at all.  Instead of making a new *merge commit* `N`, `git merge` will default to doing what Git calls a *fast-forward merge*.<sup>4</sup>  Here Git simply *checks out* commit `M` directly, and then moves the current branch name:

```
...--*--G--H--I--J
      \           \
       A--B--C--D--M   <-- feature, master (HEAD)
```

This "fast-forward merge" operation just re-uses the commit at the tip of the *other branch*.  It need not even be a merge commit.  For instance, given:

```
...--*   <-- main (HEAD)
      \
       A--B   <-- feature
```

we can "fast-forward merge" this feature to produce:

```
...--*
      \
       A--B   <-- feature, main (HEAD)
```

The fact that there was a *feature branch* here at all vanishes as this is now just a straight line of commits.  To preserve the idea that there was a feature merged, we *must* use `git merge --no-ff`:

```
...--*------M   <-- main (HEAD)
      \    /
       A--B
```

With the `git merge --no-ff`, we get the *first parent* of the new merge commit as the original main-line commit `*`.  The second parent `B` preserves the "merge bubble" that indicates a feature merge.

---

<sup>4</sup>I always say that this is poor terminology, because a fast-forward operation is *not a merge*.  There is no merging happening.  Fast-forwarding is a property of a branch name update alone.  But Git uses this terminology, so we must be prepared to understand it.

---

#### Conclusion

By merging from the main line into the feature first, and then testing, you get a chance to resolve conflicts and to test the final result.  If the merge would have been trivial (no conflicts) and/or not require testing, this gains you nothing, though.

Because this produces a "backwards" merge (wrong first-parent), it *may* be important to force a true merge afterwards, to preserve the first-parent property.  Whether and when this *second* merge is required depends on how you intend to use the repository in the future.  It's not possible to say what is is *correct* without that knowledge.

Comment: Wow what a read! (and thanks for the TL;DR and conclusion so we can see the answer and its path). I'll take a look at those wrong first-parent links.